# How to install pngquant2 on debian7?

Tags: debian

When I install with

```
apt-get install pngquant
```

the version

```
pngquant -V
```

is 1. How to I install pngquant v2 ?

regards

Comment: Upgrade to at least Jessie, or the current stable Stretch.

Comment: ok.. but how do I do that ?

Comment: upgrade `sources.list`